# Panel doesn't have border

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, border

I'm working on a project and I just started on the GUI. Since this isn't my most favorite topic, I stumbled real quick on something not working quite right. Everything (PacmanGrid,PacmanScore) is shown correctly but the borders I wrote for the PacmanScore Panel! Anyway here is the code, hope someone can help.

```
public class PacmanFrame extends JFrame{



public PacmanFrame() {
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setTitle("Pacman");
    PacmanGrid p1=new PacmanGrid();
    PacmanScore p2 = new PacmanScore();


    this.add(p1,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.add(p2,BorderLayout.EAST);
    super.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    super.repaint();
    pack();
    super.setVisible(true);


}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    PacmanFrame p1 = new PacmanFrame();
}

 }
```

**PacmanScore**

```
public class PacmanScore extends JPanel{
private TitledBorder t3 = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Menu");
private Border etched = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(Color.WHITE, Color.white);


public PacmanScore() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,800));
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    t3.setBorder(etched);
    setBorder(t3);

    setVisible(true);
    setOpaque(true);


}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.drawString("Score: ", 20, 400);

}

}
```

PacmanGrid is also extended by a Panel and draws the classical PacmanGrid using predefined patterns. But I don't think it is relevant since the problem is clearly on the PacmanScore Panel. I will post the code if anyone needs tho.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.setColor(Color.white);
    g2.drawString("Score: ", 20, 400);

}
```

You didn't override paint() properly because you didn't invoke super.paint() and therefore the border is not painted.

**Don't override paint(). Custom painting is done by overriding `paintComponent()`.**

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [A Closer Look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) for more information.

Why are you even doing custom painting? Just add a JLabel to the panel.

Also, Swing components (except for top level windows) are visible by default so there is no need to make the panel visible.

Comment: Thanks this was it! Thank you so much